# Need to initialize serial connection with screen

Tags: python, serial, screen, arduino

My Problem:
I've got an Arduino connected to my Pi via /dev/ttyUSB0 and I always have to initialize the connection via screen, otherwise I cannot send any values via Bash or Python.

What I'm doing:
From the Arduino I receive sensor values like this:

```
<43.30,43.50>
<43.30,43.70>
<43.50,43.70>
<43.60,43.30>
<43.50,43.60>
<43.50,43.60>
<43.50,44.10>
<43.50,43.60>
<43.30,43.60>
<43.50,43.70>
```

That data I'm parsing via Python and later Java...

I also can send data to the Arduino: 0 and 1 to turn a switch on and off.

When I connect via screen I can see the input values and send values.
Then, when I close screen, I can also use my script, eg this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
ser.write("1")
ser.close
```

But the every time I reboot my Pi, the script doesn't work until I connect via screen to /dev/ttyUSB0.
Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a `SYMLINK` (alias) for `ttyUSB0` via `/etc/udev/rules.d.`

[See here](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/)

Comment: I am not sure about that. On my current Archlinux ttyUSB0 is available right from scratch. So maybe the OP can check first.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a time.sleep(0.5) *right after* your write. Not sure why, but I think that will get it to work.